# How to draw List Under ImageView With transparent Areas

Tags: android, listview, imageview

[image]

i was trying to let the `ListView` on `Scroll` pass the transparent area in the `ImageView`, like (Android Market) style, but it wont.
I've tried to set `Padding` to the `ListView` and still the problem appears, disable `Clipping`,

- the green area should be transparent.
- the red is the list.
- and the blue pointer points to sample area that should be
  transparent, but    the clipping cuts the children's in the list.

any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: can you put the layout you are using for this. I suspect you need to play with margins not padding in this case.

Comment: @PravinCG , am wt work right now, when i get home i'll add the layout code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the ListView and the ImageView inside a FrameLayout and adjust the top padding/margin for the ListView to suit your needs.
This way the ImageView will be drawn on top of the ListView.

Also, make sure that the ImageView doesn't have any background color defined and that the imageview's source png image is transparent.